# Trouble to persist data in h2 db for wso2am between container restarts

Tags: wso2, dockerfile, wso2-api-manager

Folks,
I have launched ws02am v2.0.0 using docker and h2 db in one container using the following github guide: [Dockerfile for WS02 API Manager](https://github.com/wso2/dockerfiles/tree/master/wso2am) I have also attached the host volume, but I don't believe the h2 db is persisting the data between container restarts.

Here is my run cmd: `./run.sh -v 2.0.0 -m /var/local`

I have confirmed login to Carbon API Manager and the api's dont show up after restart.

What am I missing? How do I configure such that the h2 db files are stored in a volume on my host and shared with multiple wso2am containers?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The volume mounting functionality is not working like that at the moment. It is simply copying the files in '/var/local' folder to container '/mnt/wso2/' path.

In order to persist the APIs, you need to use external database running on your host machine and configure wso2am to point to the external database. Also content of

> '< wso2am >/repository/deployment/server/'

path needs to be mounted to a separate volume. (These functionalities are not supported by the scripts and you need to do that manually).

If you are using puppet provisioning method you can use [this guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/PM210/Datasources). Else, you have to manually configure datasources.xml file to point to the external database.

You can find the different docker based deployment patterns for api-manager in [here](https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/tree/master/docker-compose).

Comment: I want to run this setup in docker. Are you saying I need to have a separate  container with the database and point this container to the container with the database? In addition I would need to mount a volume so that the database container can persist the data.

Comment: Yes. You also need to mount content of '<wso2am>/repository/deployment/server/'  directory to persist an API.

Comment: Anuruddha, I have additional questions based on the new link you have shared with various patterns of deployment.

Comment: Can you please point me to which pattern I should use: https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/tree/master/docker-compose

Also it is asking for username/pwd/email when I type the following command: docker login docker.wso2.com I dont know how to register for it

Can you please point me to a guide please?

Comment: You need to register at https://wso2.com/user/register and use those credentials in docker login. The pattern depends on your scenario.